# Missing type arguments for generic class when creating a vector

Tags: java

I basically did the following

```
Vector<String> one = new Vector<String>();
one.add("hello");
one.add("mellow");
Vector<String> two = new Vector<String>();
two.add("man");
two.add("boy");
two.add("women");
```

If I try to add the following code I get warning

```
Vector bigVector = new Vector();
bigVector.add(one);
bigVector.add(two);
```

So i was wondering how is it possible to add vector one and two inside the bigVector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning you get in `Vector bigVector` is because you're using [raw types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html). Use `Vector<Vector<String>>` to avoid the warning.

In case you're using `Vector` from `java.util` package, I highly recommend you to replace it by `java.util.List` and `java.util.ArrayList`.

More info:

- [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/1065197)
- [Why is Java Vector class considered obsolete or deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1386275/1065197)

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, I also read the two links you posted. I am actually solving the same problem here maybe you will have an idea how to help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33056591/getting-error-on-nested-loop-to-generate-combinations

Answer (score -1):

Use `bigVector.addAll(one);`
`bigVector.addAll(two);`  all values of vector will get added. `add()` will add one element but `addAll()` is used to add collection. Or instead of using Vector use ArrayList. Vector is  a synchronized collection, if you don't have any specific requirement then use ArrayList.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean? So if i do bigVector.add(one); That means only "hello" or only "mellow" gets added to bigVector??

Comment: No if you add another vector it will not add its elements to bigVector. If you want to add vector one elements to bigVector then use addAll() method

Comment: I am basically adding the vector to the bigvector so i have something looking like this [['hello,'mellow'],['man','boy','women']] after adding both vectors

Comment: Using `addAll` will copy the elements from one `Vector` to another, while using `add` will add the entire `Vector` as element of the container.