# Getting error on nested loop to generate combinations

Tags: java

I am dealing with a vector like this that has other vectors with some text inside it: `[['manny','floyd'],['pacman','money','goat'],['mayweather','pacquiao']]`

This is how I have declared vectors

```
Vector<String> one = new Vector<String>();
one.add("hello");
one.add("mellow");
Vector<String> two = new Vector<String>();
two.add("man");
two.add("boy");
two.add("women");

Vector<Vector<String>> bigVector = new Vector<Vector<String>>();
bigVector.add(one);
bigVector.add(two);
```

I am attempting to generate all possible combo of one word from first vector and one word from second vector such as

```
manny pacman mayweather
manny pacman pacquiao
manny money mayweather
manny money pacquiao
```

This is my code so far

```
for(int i = 0; i<bigVector.size(); i++){
   for(int j=i; j<bigVector.get(i).size; j++){
     for(int x = i + 1; j<bigVector.get(x).size; x++){
       //Print here
    }
  }
}
```

Every time I try to print something like 
`System.out.println(bigVector.get(i).get(j) + bigVector.get(j+1))` I am getting lots of errors and i am not sure how to proceed.

All i can understand is that the outside loop should select each vector then the second loop inside that should select first element of first vector and second vector and third vector and fourth vector etc..

I would appreciate if someone can show how this is done.

**Additional Notes**

I am trying to make a generic function so the number of words inside each individual vectors can vary and also the number of vectors inside the big vector can vary which is **what is making this problem Difficult**

Comment: The values are store is list?

Comment: Basically you have vectors inside a vector and each individual vectors has words.

Comment: Could you share the vector declaration?

Comment: @ShiladittyaChakraborty please take a look now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't know how many inner vectors there are, it may be easier to reason with a recursive solution.

```
static void printWords(List<Vector<String>> bigVector) {
    printWords(bigVector, "");
}
static void printWords(List<Vector<String>> bigVector, String accumulator) {
    if(bigVector.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println(accumulator);
    }
    else {
        for(String word : bigVector.get(0)) {
            printWords(bigVector.subList(1, bigVector.size()), accumulator + " " + word);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is working fine. You are right its easy to use recursive function.

Answer (score 0):

For sake of understanding, consider all 3 vectors have same size= 3 (so valid indices are 0,1,2 ) , Now whats happening here is :

1. Suppose Outermost loop is starting last iteration, current value of i=2 ,   `for(int i = 0; i<bigVector.size(); i++){`
2. Now for second loop , values of `j=i` so j=2.
3. Now 3rd loop , values of `x=i+1` hence x=3 , voila, invalid index ,   since Vector size is 3 so `bigVector.get(x).size` will give you error.

Now that you've understood error, you can easily come up with its solution, and that is what i'am leaving for you to enhance for observatory and problem solving skills :)

Comment: Also this approach would work if there are x number of vectors inside the main vector?